Y-axis count incorrect in ggplot2 dotplot
I'm creating a dot plot using ggplot2 in R to visualize the distribution of Sepal.Length in the iris dataset. However, the y-axis shows values from 0 to 1 as if it's a density plot, when I need it to show actual frequency counts.
Here's the code I'm using:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_dotplot(method = 'histodot')


Additionally, I noticed that the upper part of the plot gets trimmed when resizing, as shown in the image below.

How can I fix these issues?

It is a know issue in ggplot2 (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5787) and won't be remedied.

But you can try ggdist::geom_dots(subguide = "axis") instead.
